# How to package and find images in an exe made with pyinstaller python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have an application in python 3.8 of which I need to create an exe or sh (Which I can do with pyinstaller). My problem is that in order for this application to work I need a folder to be created in C: or etc, and a text file and two images must be placed in this folder. How can I get pyinstaller to package these extra files and then save them in the C: folder. Creating the folder and depositing the files there is not the problem, the problem is how do I get the files to be packaged inside the exe and where my application should look for them to take them and copy them to the folder it creates.

Comment: Read the PyInstaller documentation about adding files to the onefile.

Comment: What you actually want is an installer. Firstly you create your exe with pyinstaller and use another program such as [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to package all the files you need into an installer exe where the user can specify a location for your project files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
pyinstaller --add-data "path_to_your_files;." example.py
```

OR

```
pyinstaller --add-data "path_to_your_files;desired_path_inside_your_package" example.py
```